# Primefaces 5 FileUploadEvent, not all files are uploading

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, multifile-uploader

I am developing a page in Primefaces 5 and using p:fileUpload tag in advanced mode to upload multiple files.

I have got the file upload working fine, but while I was testing I noticed that sometimes not all the files were actualy uploaded.  Ex: I upload 6 files and only 4 files actually upload.

As I was looking through the trace log I also noticed that the method only ran 4 times (previous example), leading me to believe that only 4 ajax requests out of the expected 6 where made.

In Page

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:fileUpload   fileUploadListener="#{fileUploaderBean.uploadFile}"
                     mode="advanced"
                     dragDropSupport="true"
                     multiple="true"
                     update="filesId"
                     sizeLimit="100000"
                     ajax="true"/>
<p:outputPanel id="filesId">
     <p:dataTable    value="#{fileUploaderBean.uploadedFiles}" 
                     var="uploadedFile" 
                     id="filesTable" 
                     action="#{fileUploaderBean.testAjax}">
           <p:column headerText="Uploaded File/s">
                 <h:outputText value="#{uploadedFile}" />
           </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Bean

```
private List<UploadedFile> filesList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<UploadedFile>());
private List<String> uploadedFiles = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

public void uploadFile (FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) throws IOException 
{
    LOGGER.info("Running uploadFile fileUploadEvent={}", fileUploadEvent);

    saveFileToStagingFolder(fileUploadEvent.getFile().getFileName(), fileUploadEvent.getFile().getInputstream());
    uploadedFiles.add(fileUploadEvent.getFile().getFileName());

    LOGGER.info("uploadFile process complete");
}
```

Comment: That's really odd. What happens in the browser js console (on the network tab) during the 5th and 6th requests? Also remove sizeLimit restriction to make sure that isn't somehow malfunctioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

I only had this in my web.xml had forgoten to add the filter itself

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Looks like the FileUploader will work without it but not very well at all.  Would think a configuraton error like that would of log something to indicate where the problem was.